# EditText returns old value instead of Updated value

Tags: android, android-studio, get, android-edittext, getvalue

I got database entries and displayed them in edit text. I want to change it and update it. But even if I am able change, when I try to get text from EditText it returns its old value instead of updated value.

```
private void getServicesFromLayout(View view){

       ...........
            if(checkDatabase() == null){
                try{
                    companyNo = Integer.parseInt(mCompanyNumber.getText().toString());
                    seasonNo = Integer.parseInt(mPeriodNumber.getText().toString());
                    servicePath = mServicePath.getText().toString();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                addNewService(servicePath,companyNo,seasonNo);
            }else{
                try{
                    **companyNo = Integer.parseInt(mCompanyNumber.getEditableText().toString());
                    seasonNo = Integer.parseInt(mPeriodNumber.getText().toString());
                    servicePath = mServicePath.getText().toString();**
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int result = updateDatabase(servicePath ,companyNo ,seasonNo ,getEntryID());
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(globalContext,String.valueOf(result),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }


        }


    }
```

Here I'm checking dataabase if it's null i'm adding new service if it's not null i'm trying to update existing one. But i couldn't get new value from edittext. It returns the old value

```
mSaveConnectionInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    displayLatestEntry(getLatestServiceToDisplay());
                    if(isTestOk){
                        **getServicesFromLayout(v);**
                        isTestButtonClicked = 0;
```

Here it's called...

Comment: The value in the edit text is set from the database or from the user ?

Comment: It sets from database

Comment: Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Anyway, no hard feelings, and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Where do you use this code ? in which method (click, onCreate, or something else) ?

Comment: This code is part of a custom function that called from onCreate

Comment: if the database is updated after that, it will not affect the this code since it's called in the very beginning.

Comment: thank you solved right now... it's because of displayLatestEntry(getLatestServiceToDisplay()); when i click button directly updating edittext before i got new values...

Answer (score 0):

update your database entry when you update text from edit text.

Comment: I am updating it but i am not able to get new values from EditText.